# Unable to print data with laravel (php)

Tags: php, laravel

I tried, but don't work: i don't know why...

Page.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class takeData extends Controller
{
    public function selectdata()
    {
        $data_users = DB::select('select * from persons where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
        return view('page', ['persons' => $data_users]);
    }
}
....
```

page.blade.php

```
....
@foreach ($persons as $person)
    <p>$person</p>
@endforeach
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('takeData', 'Page@selectdata');
```

Error:
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

If I remove '@foreach ($ persons as $ person)

$ person  @endforeach' in page.blade.php everything works correctly, why is it wrong?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

On your view, change `<p>$person</p>` to this:

```
 <p>{{ $person }}</p>
```

The {{ }} is used to output data as specified in the [Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade).

Comment: {{ $person->id }} or {{ $person }} have same problem

Comment: @Helpme The only other area I can think of that could go wrong is in your query. Do you know if it works correctly? If it doesn’t, you can read more about it in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#introduction But, I’d try doing something like $data_users = DB::table(‘persons’)->where(‘id’, 1)->get();

Comment: Solved, solution: "array('per..." instead of "['per..."

Comment: @Helpme ah okay. Good luck with your app.